# Crear rutas de Api en Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, api

Debido a que el archivo no se encuentra en esta version y me refiero a `routes/api.php`. Esta versión solo incluye un solo archivo `routes.php` mi problema es que como podría definir rutas de api en esta versión. Actualmente lo hago de forma web:

```
Route::get('/api/menus','Api\MenusController@index');
```

lo cual ni siquiera esta bien, debido a que en `>route list` esta usando el *middleware* web, por lo tanto me funciona pero no es lo más correcto para hacer separación de ambas ramas.

Luego entonces...

> **¿Que puedo hacer para la configuración de las rutas api?.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso hay que modificar el ServiceProvider respectivo y agregar otro archivo de rutas (aunque se puede solucionar de muchas maneras):

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
<?php
...
class RouteServiceProvider ...
{
    ...

    public function map(Router $router)
    {
        $this->mapWebRoutes($router);

        // agregar esto
        $this->mapApiRoutes($router);
    }

    // agregar esto
    protected function mapApiRoutes(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group([
            'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Api', 'middleware' => 'api',
        ], function ($router) {
            require app_path('Http/api-routes.php');
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Funciona, más sin embargo me tira un `401 (Unauthorized)`

Comment: Bueno, eso ya es un detalle mínimo que puede depurar fácilmente.